# Code first database generation enquiry

Tags: c#, database, model-view-controller, ef-code-first

I just have a question about when the code first is generated on visual studio

what does this do? is it ok to remove this from the generated code?

P.S. i did google but couldnt find a relative answer to the code first database scenario

```
[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be removed without consequence if you want to, although it's not doing any real harm as is.

Removing it won't break the build, it will just mean that the issue will be reported by the code analysis tool.

It is used to 'hide' messages that developers are happy to leave in the code.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation :) i now know its purpose, got to love discovering the depths of MVC :) cheers!

Comment: Is there any documentation of this functionality? If so, it would be good to include that in your post.